# How to load multiple objects from json?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert json data into a dict by using load() but I'm unable to do so if I have more than one object. For example, the code below works perfectly, I can dump 'dog' into a json file and then I can load 'dog' and print it out as a dict.

```
import json

dog = {
        "name":"Sally",
        "color": "yellow",
        "breed": "lab",
        "age": 2,
      },

with open("Pets.json","w") as output_file:
     json.dump(dog,output_file)

with open("Pets.json","r") as infile:
      dog_dict = json.load(infile)

      print(dog_dict)
```

Output:

[{'name': 'Sally', 'color': 'yellow', 'breed': 'lab', 'age': 2}]

However, let's say I add an object 'cat' to the existing code:

```
dog = {
        "name":"Sally",
        "color": "yellow",
        "breed": "lab",
        "age": 2,
      },

cat = {
        "name":"Daniel",
        "color": "black",
        "breed": "unknown",
        "age": 8,
      }    
with open("Pets.json","w") as output_file:
     json.dump(dog,output_file)
     json.dump(cat,output_file)

with open("Pets.json","r") as infile:
     dog_dict = json.load(infile)
     cat_dict = json.load(infile)

     print(dog_dict)
     print(cat_dict)
```

I can successfull dump 'dog' and 'cat' it into the json file, but when I try to load both 'dog' and 'cat' as dicts, I get an error message:

```
 dog_dict = json.load(infile)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
return loads(fp.read(), 
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
 return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
 raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 65 (char 64)
```

Comment: Do you really want that comma at the end of the `dog` assignment? You're creating a one-element tuple containing the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one json thing you dump to a file.  `json.load` will try to load the whole file, it doesn't find the first instance of a valid json object

You could combine them into an array

```
j_obj = [dog, cat]
```

Or create a new dict

```
j_obj = {'dog': dog, 'cat': cat}
```

Then `j_obj` can be dumped to a file and read back and you'll still be able to get `dog` and `cat` back individually if you need them that way

A quick note.  In your first example, the trailing `,` on the dog object actually makes what your dumping a json array, which is what you are printing out

```
[{'name': 'Sally', 'color': 'yellow', 'breed': 'lab', 'age': 2}]
```

It's not just a dog dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Before dumping, include your objects in a list, then dump them:

```
dog = {
        "name":"Sally",
        "color": "yellow",
        "breed": "lab",
        "age": 2,
      },

cat = {
        "name":"Daniel",
        "color": "black",
        "breed": "unknown",
        "age": 8,
      }
all_objects = [dog, cat]

with open("Pets.json","w") as output_file:
     output_file.write(json.dumps(all_objects ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON module doesn't append it automatically.
If you want your JSON to contain a number of objects use an array as insert your dictionaries into it. the dump the array